# Set image offset of ImageBrush?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a large image in memory which I convert to an `System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush` and use it as the `Fill` for a `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`. You can move this rectangle around with your cursor.

Basically I want to use the rectangle as a "viewport". Thus I need to change which parts of the image get displayed within the rectangle, i.e., define a rectangular subsection of the image.

How can I do that?

I see [ImageBrush.Viewport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewport.aspx) but that doesn't seem to mean the same thing.

---

I'm open to alternative solutions that don't involve a rectangle, such as drawing directly on a canvas or something, but AFAIK WPF doesn't let you access pixel data directly (at least not easily).

Comment: Do you have a large image and you have a smaller rectangle on top of it. As you move the rectangle you want to display whats inside the rectangle somewhere else? Kind of like a zoom control?

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI: Would be similar to a zoom control yes. Specifically though, I need something like the "capture screen" option of One Note. Basically I take a screen capture of the entire desktop to freeze it, then make the screen go whitish by overlaying a semi-transparent window, and then the user can click and draw a triangle which will show the portion of the frozen screenshot he's selecting.

Comment: I think I might switch to WinForms...then I can draw directly on the window via `Graphics.DrawImage` I believe.

Comment: Oh man please stop using Winforms. No one should use that framework anymore

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI: Well no one's given me an answer yet, and AFAICT this is a lot harder to do in WPF than WinForms. This app is very minimal on the GUI side of things anyway.

Comment: First of all everyone is the US is probably sleeping

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI: Was only 10pm west coast when I posted this. But that's OK. I'm going to call it a night too.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this your going to have to create your own rectangle user control to allow the user to create/resize a rectangle. Then I would create a CroppedBitmap of the image in the rectangle portion 
 [Cropped Bitmap MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap.aspx) 
 [Stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881865/saving-a-wpf-canvas-as-an-image)

#### Edit

No, no, no @Mark, You dont turn the CroppedBitmap into a UserControl. You create a USerControl that exposed the CroppedBitmap. Basically, you create a UserControl with the following DependencyProperties

1. The Image
2. The Width of he cropped portion
3. The Height of the cropped portion
4. The Left of the cropped portion
5. Top of the cropped portion

Then as soon as any of these properties your DP callback will do a RenderTargetBitmap Crop of the new region.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to turn the CroppedBitmap into a user control. There's no "OnRender" function, so how do I control what gets drawn?