# C#/WPF - Load Image, Free-form Draw Over It, Save Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mouseevent, draw

I am creating an image segmentation program and a small part of it is the ability to load in an image, draw over it with a pen tool and then save it.

At current my program can load an image and display it in an Image object in WPF.

I tried adding some mouse events like so;

```
    Graphics g;
    Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red, 1);
    bool drawing = false;
    System.Windows.Point previousPoint;

    private void mainImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        drawing = true;
        previousPoint = e.GetPosition(mainImage);
    }

    private void mainImage_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        drawing = false;
    }

    private void mainImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!drawing) { return; }

        if (e.GetPosition(mainImage).Equals(previousPoint)) { return; };

        g.DrawLine(pen, (float)e.GetPosition(mainImage).X, (float)e.GetPosition(mainImage).Y, (float)previousPoint.X,
            (float)previousPoint.Y);

    }
```

The problem here is that Graphics is not initialized and I don't know how to do so with an Image object, or if that is even possible.

Am I trying to reinvent the wheel here? It seems like it's quite a trivial problem but I can't find what I'm looking for. Another way I thought that might work is to use an ink canvas and load an image into it, but I couldn't find a way to do that either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use a `Graphics` object and rendering via GDI, you may find it a lot easier to do everything directly via WPF objects instead, specifically through a `Canvas`:

[Drawing on a canvas with mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037753/wpf-drawing-on-canvas-with-mouse-events)

[Saving a WPF canvas as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881865/saving-a-wpf-canvas-as-an-image)

Basically, you could render the image as the background to the canvas and then follow the links above for the rendering and saving.

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"image.png", UriKind.Relative));
canvas.Background = brush;
```