# How to save a right to left canvas as an image wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I wanted to save a canvas to an image. I searched on internet and I found this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881865/saving-a-wpf-canvas-as-an-image)

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)canvas.RenderSize.Width,
    (int)canvas.RenderSize.Height, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(canvas);

var crop = new CroppedBitmap(rtb, new Int32Rect(50, 50, 250, 250));

BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(crop));

using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("logo.png"))
{
    pngEncoder.Save(fs);
}
```

I tried it out but it didn't work as expected. It works fine when the canvas's flow direction is left to right but when it's right to left the saved image is completely flipped. Is there any way to fix it.

[image: canvas]

[image: result]

Comment: Please provide more details. What are the child elements of the Canvas? How does it look? How does the rendered image look? How is it supposed to look? Why are you cropping a part out of the rendered image?

Comment: I don't know what I did. I just copied the code in my method.

Comment: I added the pictures.

Comment: The second image is the original Canvas, or just how you want it to look like? In any case, the CroppedBitmap makes no sense here. Write `pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));`